# Show the union of two subrings is generally not a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that the union of two subrings is a subring if and only if either of the subring is contained in the other.
I have no trouble in going from right to left but cannot seem to be able to go from left to right.

Comment: If neither $A\subseteq B$ nor $B\subseteq A$, there exists an $a\in A$ which is not in $B$, and a $b\in B$ which is not in $A$. Show that $a+b\notin A\cup B$, that is, $A\cup B$ is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R_1,R_2\subset R$ be subrings such that $R_1\cup R_2$ is a subring.

Assume $r\in R_1\setminus R_2$. For every $r_2\in R_2$ we have $r_1+r_2\in R_1\cup R_2$.

If $r+r_2\in R_2$ then $r=(r+r_2)-r_2\in R_2$, contradiction.

If $r+r_2\in R_1$ then $r_2=(r+r_2)-r\in R_1$.

Therefore $R_2\subset R_1$.